# spring cloud config discovery enabled with basic authentication

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I am using a Spring Cloud Config server with the following eureka and basic security configuration.
The client gets the config server uri correctly through eureka, however cannot access to the properties data because basic authentication is not working on the client side.

I would appreciate some help to understand how to fix this situation.

The Spring Cloud Config server is the following:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/actuator/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/health
eureka.instance.homePageUrl=https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=pass
```

The client configuration is the following:

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
eureka.instance.non-secure-port-enabled=false
eureka.instance.secure-port-enabled=true
eureka.instance.statusPageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/actuator/info
eureka.instance.healthCheckUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/health
eureka.instance.homePageUrl: https://${eureka.hostname}:${server.port}/
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=trm-config-server
spring.cloud.config.username=admin
spring.cloud.config.password=pass
spring.cloud.config.name=users-ws
```

Comment: User name and password need to go in the eureka service url

Comment: If that is the case, Why using basic authentication when you are publishing the user and password through Eureka?